# "Change in scope" versus "Change of scope" versus "Change to (the) scope"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> Any changes **in** scope will be addressed during this meeting.

or

> Any changes **of** scope will be addressed during this meeting.

or

> Any changes **to** (the) scope will be addressed during this meeting.

Proposition madness!  I believe that I can make a case for each choice, but what does the board think?

My intuition is that if one chooses the "to" preposition then I would have to include "the" before "scope," whereas "the" could be omitted from the first two options.

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Proposition madness might occur during long weekends of constitution planning, but here we like to think we're fact-based. ;) I would go with *changes in scope*.

Comment: @Susan: So would I - [*"any changes **in the** scope"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22any+changes+in+the+scope%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) about four times more common in Google Books than ***to the*** (where ***of [the]*** is far less common). I wouldn't include ***the*** unless it was something like ***changes in the scope of the project***. Which seemed to me to be a general tendency in Google Books.

Answer (score 1):

The most common preposition in this context is "in":

> Any changes in scope will be addressed during this meeting.

"Of" would be an acceptable but uncommon alternative. The third is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

There's always **"Scope Changes"** to let you avoid the issue entirely.